# Calculate individual means for each section/slice of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

For a current project, I am planning to calculate the mean values for `rating_recommend`. The object is sliced by `stock_symbol` as first and `quarter` of the year as second slicing criterium.

At the moment, the output file is however showing the general mean for all categories, as shown below:

```
stock_symbol  quarter   rating_recommend 
A             2008Q2    1.270 
A             2008Q3    1.270 
A             2008Q4    1.270 
A             2009Q1    1.270 
A             2009Q2    1.270 
A             2009Q3    1.270
```

Goal is to get individual means for each of the categories:

```
stock_symbol  quarter   rating_recommend 
A             2008Q2    1.123 
A             2008Q3    1.321 
A             2008Q4    1.674 
A             2009Q1    1.003
A             2009Q2    1.245 
A             2009Q3    1.177
```

Is there any smart tweak to make this work? The relevant code section looks as follows:

```
# Datetime conversion
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['quarter'] = df['date'].dt.to_period('Q')

# Definition of the data objects
def get_top_n_bigram(row):
    # Convert quantitative data and remove null values
    df['rating_recommend'] = pd.to_numeric(df['rating_recommend'], errors='coerce')
    return df['rating_recommend'].mean()

# Grouping data and assigning this as a new dataframe
newdf = df.groupby(['stock_symbol', 'quarter']).apply(get_top_n_bigram).to_frame(name = 'rating_recommend')

# Exporting the dataframe to Excel
newdf.to_excel('total_bigrams_pro.xlsx')
```

Last but not least, the sample data looks like this:

```
[
{"gld_index": "1-0", "stock_symbol": "AMG", "gld_id": "7172", "date": "2013-01-01", "rating_recommend": 0, "rating_outlook": 1, "rating_ceo": 1, "scr_avg": 1.0, "scr_balance": 1.0, "scr_values": 1.0, "scr_opportunities": 1.0, "scr_benefits": 1.0, "scr_management": 1.0},
{"gld_index": "1-2", "stock_symbol": "AMG", "gld_id": "7172", "date": "2011-09-15", "rating_recommend": 2, "rating_outlook": null, "rating_ceo": 2, "scr_avg": 4.0, "scr_balance": 5.0, "scr_values": null, "scr_opportunities": 4.0, "scr_benefits": 5.0, "scr_management": 4.5},
{"gld_index": "1-0", "stock_symbol": "MMM", "gld_id": "446", "date": "2017-05-14", "rating_recommend": 2, "rating_outlook": 1, "rating_ceo": 2, "scr_avg": 4.0, "scr_balance": 4.0, "scr_values": 5.0, "scr_opportunities": 3.0, "scr_benefits": 3.0, "scr_management": 4.0}
]
```

Comment: can you add the `date` column to the example?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The date column has the format `"date": "2013-01-01"`, `"date": "2011-09-15"` etc. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it should work:

```
newdf = df.groupby(['stock_symbol', 'quarter']).mean()
```

Comment: Nailed it, many thanks. Just as a quick check: is there any way to perform the same mean calculation for further columns within the same file?

Comment: Yes, mean is applied to all columns without columns in `groupby`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. When adding more columns, I nonetheless only receive one column with mean values. How can that be?

Comment: Hard to say without sample dataframe. You can enclose it as part of this question or if there is another problem maybe ask next question.

Comment: I have added some of the sample data to the question. Hope there is a straightforward tweak that can lead to the intended consideration of the other numerical columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `rating_recommend` at once instead of each row inside the loop:

```
# Datetime conversion
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['quarter'] = df['date'].dt.to_period('Q')

# Convert quantitative data and remove null values
df['rating_recommend'] = pd.to_numeric(df['rating_recommend'], errors='coerce')

# Grouping data and assigning this as a new dataframe
newdf = df.groupby(['stock_symbol', 'quarter'])['rating_recommend'].mean().reset_index()

# Exporting the dataframe to Excel
newdf.to_excel('total_bigrams_pro.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks, that is leading to `pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`. though. Without the `.reset_index()` addition the script works well and as intended.